# Multiple div windows on clicking button

Tags: jquery, html

I could not frame the title properly.But the question is, I am working on a application form which ask the user to enter address.I have kept the address1 and address2 in two seperate divs where my address2 is hidden.I provided a button for address1 div upon clicking address2 div opens. In address2 there are two more buttons when clicked 'ADD', the clone copy of address2 should open and when clicked on 'REMOVE' the div should hide. The problem is I am able to ADD and REMOVE div.but when I clicked ADD button of address2 many windows are popping up.I only need one to pop up as a user requirement.

So far I am able to write this code.Tell me where I am going wrong.
 Code is below

```
</div>
<div class="div1 target">Address
<div>
Primary<span class="red">*</span> <input type="text" placeholder="Address 1" id="add1"    name="add1" required/>

</div>
<div>
City<span class="red">*</span> 
<input type="text" placeholder="City" id="city" name="city" required/>
</div>


<div>
Country<span class="red">*</span> 

<select name="country" id="country">
<option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Country </option>
<option id="coun1" value="coun1">Country1</option>
<option id="coun2" value="coun2">Country2</option>
<option id="coun3" value="coun3">Country3</option>
<option id="coun4" value="coun4">Country4</option>
</select>
State<span class="red">*</span> 
<select name="state"  id="state">
<option selected="selected" value=""> Choose State </option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State1</option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State2</option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State3</option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State4</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State5</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State6</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State7</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State8</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State9</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State10</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State11</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State12</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State13</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State14</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State15</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State16</option>
</select>

</div>

<div>Zip/Postal Code<span class="red">*</span>  
<input type="text" placeholder="Zip/Postal" id="zpc" name="zpc" required/>
</div>
<input type="button" value="add" id="add0"/>
</div>



<div class="div3 target" style="display:none">Address
<div>
Primary<span class="red">*</span> <input type="text" placeholder="Address 1" id="add1"   name="add1"         required/>

</div>
<div>
City<span class="red">*</span> 
<input type="text" placeholder="City" id="city" name="city" required/>
</div>


<div>
Country<span class="red">*</span> 

<select name="country" id="country">
<option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Country </option>
<option id="coun1" value="coun1">Country1</option>
<option id="coun2" value="coun2">Country2</option>
<option id="coun3" value="coun3">Country3</option>
<option id="coun4" value="coun4">Country4</option>
</select>
State<span class="red">*</span> 
<select name="state"  id="state">
<option selected="selected" value=""> Choose State </option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State1</option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State2</option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State3</option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State4</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State5</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State6</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State7</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State8</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State9</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State10</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State11</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State12</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State13</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State14</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State15</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State16</option>
</select>

</div>

<div>Zip/Postal Code<span class="red">*</span>  
<input type="text" placeholder="Zip/Postal" id="zpc" name="zpc" required/>
</div>
<input type="button" value="add" id="add"/>
<input type="button" value="remove" id="remove"/>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add0").click(function(e){
    $(".div1").after($(".div3").show());
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add").click(function(e){
    $(".div3").clone(true).insertBefore($(".div3"));
});
$("#remove").click(function(e){
    $(this).closest(".div3").hide();

});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was two mistakes first: when you insert .div3 twice there already are two .div3  and when you press add button it inserts both of them, you must use last() to avoid this.
second mistake:insertBefore($(".div3")) inserts .div3 before all .div3 tags to avoid this use must use last() again now it looks like this: $(".div3").last().clone(true).insertBefore($(".div3").last()); 
this code bellow is correct you can use it

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>

</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div1 target">Address
<div>
Primary<span class="red">*</span> <input type="text" placeholder="Address 1" id="add1"    name="add1" required/>

</div>
<div>
City<span class="red">*</span> 
<input type="text" placeholder="City" id="city" name="city" required/>
</div>


<div>
Country<span class="red">*</span> 

<select name="country" id="country">
<option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Country </option>
<option id="coun1" value="coun1">Country1</option>
<option id="coun2" value="coun2">Country2</option>
<option id="coun3" value="coun3">Country3</option>
<option id="coun4" value="coun4">Country4</option>
</select>
State<span class="red">*</span> 
<select name="state"  id="state">
<option selected="selected" value=""> Choose State </option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State1</option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State2</option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State3</option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State4</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State5</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State6</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State7</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State8</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State9</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State10</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State11</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State12</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State13</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State14</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State15</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State16</option>
</select>

</div>

<div>Zip/Postal Code<span class="red">*</span>  
<input type="text" placeholder="Zip/Postal" id="zpc" name="zpc" required/>
</div>
<input type="button" value="add" id="add0"/>
</div>



<div class="div3 target" style="display:none">Address
<div>
Primary<span class="red">*</span> <input type="text" placeholder="Address 1" id="add1"   name="add1"         required/>

</div>
<div>
City<span class="red">*</span> 
<input type="text" placeholder="City" id="city" name="city" required/>
</div>


<div>
Country<span class="red">*</span> 

<select name="country" id="country">
<option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Country </option>
<option id="coun1" value="coun1">Country1</option>
<option id="coun2" value="coun2">Country2</option>
<option id="coun3" value="coun3">Country3</option>
<option id="coun4" value="coun4">Country4</option>
</select>
State<span class="red">*</span> 
<select name="state"  id="state">
<option selected="selected" value=""> Choose State </option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State1</option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State2</option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State3</option>
<option class="st1" value="st1">State4</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State5</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State6</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State7</option>
<option class="st2" value="st2">State8</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State9</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State10</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State11</option>
<option class="st3" value="st3">State12</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State13</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State14</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State15</option>
<option class="st4" value="st4">State16</option>
</select>

</div>

<div>Zip/Postal Code<span class="red">*</span>  
<input type="text" placeholder="Zip/Postal" id="zpc" name="zpc" required/>
</div>
<input type="button" value="add" id="add"/>
<input type="button" value="remove" id="remove"/>
</div>

<script >
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add0").click(function(e){
    $(".div3").show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add").click(function(e){
    $(".div3").last().clone(true).insertBefore($(".div3").last());
});
$("#remove").click(function(e){
    if($(".div3").length!=1){
        $(this).closest(".div3").remove();
    }
    else{
        $(this).closest(".div3").hide();
    }
});
e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes the above code works. But when I remove all the added windows of .div3 class and click on add button of main window(of .div1 class) then all the removed windows just pop up. Is the functionality of the code is that way or we are doing wrong ??

Comment: it is because you hide div not remove i'v changed code now it's correct 
try it above

Comment: And there is another error I did not observe previously.If I add two address2 windows and select the country name in second window the state of first window is changing instead of second window's state